# Can not build C# project with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

I don't know what happens with my Visual Studio 2022. When I create a C++ console project, I can build the project. However, when I do the same thing for C# project, I can not build the project. I look like in the picture. Any help is truly appreciated.

I tried everything I can but it didn't work.

Comment: You didn't create a project, you only created a file. Use the "New project" wizard.

Comment: I mean F5 or Ctrl + F5 doesn't work.

Comment: I created a C# console project and what is in the picture what is seen at the end.

Comment: No, that's not how it should look like. How did you create the project?

Comment: In the menu New, New - Project. In the Create a new Project window, I choose Console App then click Next. In the Configure you new project window, I let all defaults, then click Next. In the Additional Information window, I choose .NET 6.0 (Long Term Support), check on box Do not use top lever statements, then click Next. It appears like the picture at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a bug. When a new project is created, it should appear in Solution Explorer. However your solution has no projects, and the source file appears in "Miscellaneous Files" (meaning it's not part of a project, and therefore VS won't know how to build it).

Please use the Visual Studio Installer to run a repair on your VS installation. If that doesn't help, use *Help | Send feedback | Report a problem* and include a recording of the steps you're taking to create a new project. If you link the feedback ticket here, I can make sure it gets looked at by the right people. Thanks.

Comment: I uninstall VS and then install it again. Now everything is OK. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. In future, you can try a repair which can be faster than a full reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to create a new Console App for creating and running C#
> projects
>
> Press F5, choose Debug > Start with debugging from the Visual Studio
> menu,  or select the green Start arrow and project name on the Visual
> Studio toolbar. Or, to run without debugging, press Ctrl+F5 or choose
> Debug > Start without debugging from the Visual Studio menu.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing as you did, but what I obtained in the picture in my post. I now uninstall my VS, and install it again. Hope new installation will fix it.

Comment: Try it again and Make sure that the .NET Framework is installed and configured correctly on your machine.

Check that the C# project is referencing the correct version of the .NET Framework. Upvote my answer if it helps.

Comment: I uninstall VS and then install it again. Now everything is OK. Thanks. I think errors come from the fact that my computer installed many versions of the .NET framework. I uninstall all of them and then install VS 2022 again. Now everything is OK now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have access to the nuggets that are referenced in your solution, try that you have access to each of the nugget urls in your Edge/Chrome browsers

[image]